# Issue connecting ros master to Miro-E with ethernet and wireless connection

Tags: ros-noetic, rosnode

I am new to robotics and ROS. I have a Miro-E robot and I am trying to connect the ROS from my Nvidia Jetson Nano to the robot.

The Jetson is connected to ethernet cable while the robot is wirelessly connected to the local network.

I have installed the correct version of ROS and MDK for my robot. Have started the `roscore`, but when I try to run the demo script `~/MDK/bin/shared/client_test.py yaw`, nothing happens. I debugged the nodes using `rostopic list` and i can see that the nodes are there. But they are not getting published.

I think that the issue is related to the type of connection, ethernet and wireless and the IP addresses of the master and robot, but I am not able to figure out how to resolve it.

I am on Ubuntu 20.04, Jetson version

I am attaching all the outputs that I get for each command so that I can provide as much detail I can.

```
Sourcing mdk/setup.bash...

MIRO edition: 2
MDK path: /home/jetson/mdk
MDK release: R210921
User setup: /home/jetson/.miro2/config/user_setup.bash

Local network address: 172.17.0.1 (set from miro_get_dynamic_address())
Robot network address:  (not set)
ROS master address: http://localhost:11311 (not set, assumed running locally)

Type "miro_info" to see your environment
________________________________________________________________

jetson@nano:~$ roscore
... logging to /home/jetson/.ros/log/2f4e2466-a1e8-11ee-b0f9-69983ee98962/roslaunch-nano-8087.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://172.17.0.1:37061/
ros_comm version 1.16.0


SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.16.0

NODES

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [8139]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://172.17.0.1:11311/

setting /run_id to 2f4e2466-a1e8-11ee-b0f9-69983ee98962
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [8155]
started core service [/rosout]
```

The code above is printed when we initialize the roscore. The ROS_MASTER_URI is 172.17.0.1.

```
jetson@nano:~/mdk/bin/shared$ ./client_test.py yaw
publish /miro/control/cmd_vel
publish /miro/control/kinematic_joints
publish /miro/control/cosmetic_joints
publish /miro/control/illum
publish /miro/core/mpg/push
publish /miro/control/flags
subscribe /miro/sensors/package
wait for connect...
send control flags... 
0x2
OK
```

Here are the details about the robot network settings:
ROS master: @ 127.0.0.1
Bridge: @ 127.0.0.1
Network address mode: dynamic
Static IP: not set
Dynamic IP timeout: 60 sec
ROS master IP: not set
Robot name: miro

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Micro-E platform but hopefully this is helpful.
Addresses starting with 127.x.x.x are loopback addresses, data sent on these addresses never leaves the computer.
To connect between the Jetson and the Micro-E you need to have the ROS_MASTER_URI set to use an address that's accessible on your network.
According to the Micro-E documentation, [you should be able to do this with their app](http://labs.consequentialrobotics.com/miro-e/docs/index.php?page=Husbandry_MIROapp_Home_page_ROS_settings_dialog) by setting the `ROS master location` to "Elsewhere".
This should set the robot to look for a ROS Master somewhere else on the network.
You'll also need to configure the ip address of the system you intend to host the ROS master on with `Network address of ROS master`, this configuration requires the ROS Master to be running before the robot is booted up. According to the documentation
`If you select "Elsewhere", you must provide the IP address of the machine on which roscore will be running, and it must be running already when the robot boots.`

More information on running multiple machines in ROS: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines

Comment: Thank you for your support! I have made some changes in the configuration files but still can't get the jetson to communicate with the robot.

Comment: What are the ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_IP settings for the Micro-E and the jetson?

Comment: ROBOT IP ADDRESS: 192.168.1.90
JETSON IP ADDRESS: 192.168.1.88

Sourcing mdk/setup.bash...

MIRO edition: 2
MDK path: /home/jetson/mdk
MDK release: R210921
User setup: /home/jetson/.miro2/config/user_setup.bash

Local network address: 172.17.0.1 (set from miro_get_dynamic_address())
Robot network address: 192.168.1.90 (set explicitly)
ROS master address: http://192.168.1.90:11311 (set from MIRO_ROBOT_IP)


================
BashRC
export MIRO_ROBOT_IP=192.168.1.90
source ~/mdk/setup.bash

export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.88:11311
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.88

Comment: Assuming the IP addresses are correct, the Micro-E should connect to the ROS master if it's present when the device boots. Can both machines ping eachother?

Comment: I have ran `ping 192.168.1.88` and `ping 192.168.1.90` from jetson and they both work. I cannot run pink on robot since I cannot connect to onboard computer

Comment: For the robot, the ROS_HOSTNAME should be a resolvable name on the network. The documentation defaults to `micro` which is probably fine for this. When the HOSTNAME is set it overrides ROS_IP the ROS_MASTER_URI on the micro should be `http://192.168.1.88:11311/` since you're attempting to run the master from the nano. Both the micro and the nano need to share this environment variable.

Comment: I am following this documentation: http://labs.consequentialrobotics.com/miro-e/docs/index.php?page=Developer_Profiles_Off-board. 

The ROS MASTER is running on the raspberry Pi of the Robot. I am attempting to publish client_test.py script from the Jeptson Nano. 

I run the `./client_test.py yaw` command from Nano but it returns: Unable to register with master node [http://192.168.1.90:11311]: master may not be running yet. Will keep trying.

Comment: The local network address is 172.17.0.1. I searched the `ifconfig` and that address is connected to docker0. There is also eth0 with 192.168.1.90 as ip address. Could that be the problem? The robot is not able to communicate with 172.17.0.1, but might with 192.168.1.90. If so, how can i change?

Comment: The ROS_MASTER_URI needs to be `http://192.168.1.88:11311/` on both the jetson and the Micro-E. When setting "ROS Master Location" to "Elsewhere" the Micro-E will not run its own master [according to the documentation](http://labs.consequentialrobotics.com/miro-e/docs/index.php?page=Husbandry_MIROapp_Home_page_ROS_settings_dialog). The MICRO_ROBOT_IP needs to be equal to 192.168.1.90 and the jetson's ROS_IP needs to be 192.168.1.88. The Micro-E won't be able to find 192.168.1.90:11311 because it is not running.